# Google analytic custom timing entres wrong value

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I am using custom variable to store page load time, here send  calculated time to ga function and it gets log in google analytic.

I am sending number in millisecond that google converts into seconds and shows in report.

Using below function to log this

```
 ga('send', {
         hitType: 'timing',
         timingCategory: pageName,
         timingVar: 'load_'+Date.now()+'_'+uniqueid()+'_'+$('#CLIENT_IP').val(),
         timingValue: load_time,
         timingLabel: $('#CLIENT_IP').val()
        });
```

Sometime I see it enters wrong value, looks like time missed to converted in seconds, in such scenarios I am not confident on what report I am getting from google analytic.

Can anyone let me know If I am missing here something.

Comment: Just a side note, are you collecting the users IP. If so then that violates Googled terms of usage, which, to greatly paraphrase, states that you can't collect any info that can personally identify an individual.

Comment: can you sene me link where google says it is not aalowed.

Comment: http://www.google.com/analytics/terms/us.html, section 7. Consult your privacy team/lawyers in the interpretation of what is permissible as it's not black and white.